# Redirect with Event Listener for all "No route found 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException"

Tags: symfony

How can I trigger redirect to a specific router in event listener?

There are many examples but I couldn't find one for "GetResponseForExceptionEvent". For exampe, when I pass `@roter` as an argument `$this->router....` doesn't seem to be working so on.

I checked these but I probably missed something:

- [Show a specific route instead of error page (404) - Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983082/show-a-specific-route-instead-of-error-page-404-symfony2)
- [symfony2: hook into NotFoundHttpException for redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564466/symfony2-hook-into-notfoundhttpexception-for-redirection)
- [Symfony2 redirect for event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916439/symfony2-redirect-for-event-listener)
- [Symfony2: Getting Route in Page Load Event Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505287/symfony2-getting-route-in-page-load-event-listener/11506088#11506088)
- [Redirect if the user is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487557/redirect-if-the-user-is-logged-in)

**service.yml**

```
services:
    kernel.listener.kernel_request:
        class: Booking\AdminBundle\EventListener\ErrorRedirect
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

**Event listener:**

```
namespace Booking\AdminBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class ErrorRedirect
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();

        if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            // redirect to '/' router or '/error'
            //$event->setResponse(...........);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

***You have 2 options:***

- Use an Event Listener
- Use a route that matches all the routes that don't exist and trigger an action in a controller.

Let me know if that works.

---

## Option 1

*Note:* Have a look at [Symfony2 redirect for event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916439/symfony2-redirect-for-event-listener)

<kbd>1</kbd> Pass the router to your event listener:

```
kernel.listener.kernel_request:
       class: Booking\AdminBundle\EventListener\ErrorRedirect
       arguments:
           router: "@router"
       tags:
           - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

<kbd>2</kbd> Use the router within the listener to redirect users:

```
namespace Booking\AdminBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;

class ErrorRedirect
{
    /**
     * Holds Symfony2 router
     *
     *@var Router
     */
    protected $router;

    /**
     * @param Router
     */
    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }


    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();

        if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {

            /** Choose your router here */
            $route = 'route_name';

            if ($route === $event->getRequest()->get('_route')) {
                return;
            }

            $url = $this->router->generate($route);
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            $event->setResponse($response);

        }
    }
}
```

---

## Option 2

You can create a special route that will match all routes that don't exist; You can then handle the redirect the way you want within the controller of your choice, here PageNotFoundController:

<kbd>1</kbd> At the end of app/config/routing.yml

```
pageNotFound:
    pattern:  /{path}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:PageNotFound:pageNotFound, path: '' }
    requirements:
        path: .*
```

<kbd>2</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class PageNotFoundController extends Controller
{

    public function pageNotFoundAction()
    {
        // redirect the way you want

    }

}
```

Comment: But doesn't this work only on Dev and not on Prod environments?

Comment: @NatNaydenova This looks like working on both (but I tihkn you don't care because it's been 6 years since you asked ^^)