# Redirect if route does'n exist

Tags: php, symfony

I have a question : so for examples I have an app in symfony3 which have the following routes : `/admin/login`,`admin/news`,`admin/gallery`, but the route `/admin/authentification` doesn't exist. So the idea is if the route doesn't exist I want to redirect the user to homepage `/`. Can you help me please ? Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect with Event Listener for all "No route found 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464624/redirect-with-event-listener-for-all-no-route-found-404-not-found-notfoundhtt)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not confident this is the *best* solution, but you can use a [`UrlMatcher`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.html) to check that the URL you're passing correlates to an available route:

```
/**
 * @Route("/debug")
 */

public function DebugAction(){
    $router = $this->get('router');

    //Get all the routes that exist.
    $routes = $router->getRouteCollection();
    $context = $router->getContext();

    $urlMatcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);

    $url = '/admin/login';
    try{
        //UrlMatcher::match() will throw a ResourceNotFoundException if the route 
        //doesn't exist.
        $urlMatcher->match($url);
        return $this->redirect($url);
    } catch (\Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException $e){
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
}
```

I'm not particularly keen on this solution because it relies on catching an exception, rather than checking a boolean value to determine if the route exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the rout exist.

```
function routeExists($name)
{
    // I assume that you have a link to the container in your twig extension class
    $router = $this->container->get('router');
    return (null === $router->getRouteCollection()->get($name)) ? false : true;
}
```

And depending on result, do the redirect to the rout, or to the default webpage, or whatever you need.