# Redirecting any URL not already qualified by another route

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

**Scenario**

In my Symfony2 project, I have some basic routes like `/login` and `/register` etc.

Now if someone comes along and tries to visit `/foo` or any other route not handled by any specific route, I want it to redirect them to `/`.

**My attempt**

I have routes for `/login` and some other single GET variable routes, using annotations, such as

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 * @return Response
 * @Template("AccountBundle:login.html.twig")
 */
public function loginAction()
{
    //Code!
}
```

Now I want to have another Controller/Action which handles anything else, so I tried

```
/**
 * @Route("/{some_variable}", name="url_redirect")
 * @param $some_variable string
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function redirectAction($some_variable = '')
{
    return $this->redirectOldDisciplineUrl($some_variable);
}
```

**Problem**

When I now try to visit `/login`, it doesn't visit the loginAction, but is rather caught by the one that catches anything, and I get redirected.

**Question**

How can I make sure that if my GET variable matches a specific route, it goes to that page, rather than the one that catches anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464624/redirect-with-event-listener-for-all-no-route-found-404-not-found-notfoundhtt

Comment: @TobiasXy - Thanks, I'll check that out. The second option from the accepted answer looks like what I want. I'll come back and update if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url_redirect` route should be the very last one. You should remove the `@Route` annotation from there and put the route into `app/config/routing.yml` as the last one. Or you can create an event listener for the `kernel.exception` event. You can check the order with the `router:debug` command.

Comment: Nice. Re-arranging the order of the routes in routing.yml fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry if this is not answering your question.
But I have an idea for your problem.
What if your `another Controller/Action which handles anything else`
Changed to be the main controller of your project, so that you could check the parameter to satisfy your needs.
I just thought that you could use `switch case` here. I don't know how to write this correctly, so i hope you understand.

```
/**
 * @Route("/{some_variable}", name="url_redirect")
 * @param $some_variable string
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function redirectAction($some_variable)
{
    switch($some_variable){
      case "login": {
        // Your login handler
      },
      case "register": {
        // Your register handler
      },
      default: {
        // Default handler for non-listed route
      }
    }
    return $this->redirectOldDisciplineUrl($some_variable);
}
```

Comment: That would absolutely work, but I dismissed the idea, because every time I make a new single-variable route, I'll have to add it to that switch/case.

Answer (score 0):

Why not override the 404 error handling :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-exceptioncontroller

If you do that, when you have a 404 error, you can do what you want, like process data in URL, to start a research, on try to find out what your visitor try to see ...

Create a new listener :

```
<?php
namespace YourBundleNameBundle\Bundle\Error404Bundle\Listener;


use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;

    class RedirectExceptionListener
    {
        /**
         * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
         */
        protected $em;
        protected $logger;
        protected $templating;

        function __construct(EntityManager $em, LoggerInterface $logger, EngineInterface $templating)
        {
            $this->em = $em;
            $this->logger = $logger;
            $this->templating = $templating;
        }


        /**
         * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event
         */
        public function checkRedirect(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
        {
            $exception = $event->getException();
            if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {

                // Look for a redirect based on requested URI
                // e.g....
                $uri = $event->getRequest()->getUri();
                $path = $event->getRequest()->getPathInfo();
                //doing stuff ...

                $response = new Response();

                $event->setResponse($this->templating->renderResponse('YourBundleNameBundle:Default:index.html.twig'));
            }
        }
    }
```

In the service yml file :

```
services:
    yourName.exception_listener:
        class: YourClass\Bundle\Error404Bundle\Listener\RedirectExceptionListener
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@logger', '@templating']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: checkRedirect }
```