# Organizing assets in Symfony3

Tags: symfony, assetic

I still have some problems to handle my assets in symfony. The [best practices](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html) say, I should store my assets in `web/`. 
But I dont like to store my raw sass files there, because its a public folder and I think only compiled or static files should be stored there.

Thats why I store them (js and sass) currently in `app/Resources`. And my `assetic.read_from` is `app/Resources`. But then there are some bundles, that are symlinked by `assets:install` to `web/bundles/`.

And now, when I want to include this bundle-assets in my twig files, I have to go there by `../../web/bundles/..` in the stylesheets block. That doesnt look very clean, so I did a symlink  `app/Resources/bundles->web/bundles/` and that works.

But I still think its too much fiddle and I would like to know if there is a cleaner way that better collects my assets in one place.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use AsseticBundle, it was even removed in default symfony-standard 2.8. Managing frontend assets with php is workaround for someone who really don't want to use "the right tools"

I personally keep my source files in `/assets/` and with Grunt JS I compile them to `/web/assets/` which later is served from `assets.somedomain.com` through CDN

2 years ago I wrote post about managing assets with symfony, it's still valid and up to date. You might want to check it out.

http://konradpodgorski.com/blog/2014/06/23/better-way-to-work-with-assets-in-symfony-2/

I should extend post by things I learned since then but always not enough time :)

Comment: thats a late reaction, but I dont want to use neither external cdns nor javascript based css management.  So I prefer the pure php/server way to compile and manage my assets

Comment: I respect your decision but still think it's more complicated than setting up correct process once and then replicating it in every project. Unless you use pure CSS without any compilers, then just put them in /web/assets/ and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't use `web/` folder for your assets.

I often work with `less` and other file format which are afterward processed and minified.
The solution to your problem seems simple to me: Use two folder in the `web/` folder.

The first folder would be your `source/` folder. In which you would place all your `sass` files. You will add a `.htaccess` file to this same folder, and deny all access (you can copy from the `.htaccess` file in the `src/` folder).

Then a second folder, lets call it `assets` which will hold all your compiled and minified assets.

That should do the trick... ;)

You may be interested in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464624/redirect-with-event-listener-for-all-no-route-found-404-not-found-notfoundhtt) as well. It may help to hide futher the existence of your `source/` folder. ;)

If you really don't want to have your sources files in the `web/` folder, then [loot at this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/uglifyjs.html), it should help you place your sources files in your bundle.

Comment: why should I store my assets in a common /web folder? I want to have it stored within the bundle itself

Comment: Mostly because Twig will read assets from `web/` folder. As exemple, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/style.css') }}">` will only works if you assets folder is in `web/` directory. Your `source/` folder though, can be in your bundle. Then you can embed a small services which will works with your compilier/minifier for CSS/JS, and have it write the files in the `web/` directory. Keep in mind the good practice, it's important to have a smooth working project. ;)

Comment: @Asara It would be time for you to pick a solution, both Konrad and me provided you with suited solutions for your problem. No matter what, your compiled/minified assets will be public, there is no work around it. We both provided you with a solution to protect your sources.