# How to use session in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm getting a hard time trying to understand how symfony session works.
And couldn't find the answer I'm looking for here on S.O. or other external sources.

[SETTINGS]

- Symfony 3
- `SiteEntity` (Hold website informations such as site URL, site name, etc)
- Website structure is made from a layout around the page (layout.html.twig)

[THE PROBLEM]

Quite easy to understand, I just can't figure out where to start my session. 
What I did for now was create this action in `SiteController`

```
public function sessionAction(Request $request) {
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $site=$em->getRepository('SiteBundle:Site')->findOneBy(array('url'=>$request->getSchemeAndHttpHost()));
    if($site) {
        $session=new Session();
        $session->set('id',$site->getId());
        $session->set('url',$site->getUrl());
        $session->set('name',$site->getName());
    } else {
        [...]
    }
}
```

How can I call this function on website loading to create the session?

Also, is it the right way to do it?

Comment: `$session = $this->get('session');`

Comment: No explanations... And doesn't seems to answer my question.

Comment: To get a session object you don't `$session=new Session();` but `$session = $this->get('session');`. Not sure what other explanations you need.

Comment: I want to init my session object here... Not get it.. If you're suggesting that I should get my session object to init it, it's considered as bad practice (symfony doc).

Comment: Thing is, a session is auto initiated in Symfony when you need it. So if this is an authenticated request, you already have a session at this point.

Comment: If you're using the full framework, there's a session service in the container. Hence `$this->get('session');`, which then allows you to make calls against it: http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/SessionInterface.html

Comment: Right, that much is said in the [Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html). And just like the second pen state : "**While it is recommended to explicitly start a session**, a session will actually start on demand, that is, if any session request is made to read/write session data." It's still explicitly recommended to start it yourself. Thus, this doesn't answer my question as how do I call `sessionAction` when I load my site

Comment: Ive never ever needed to start it myself.  I think youre trying to solve a problem that doesnt exist.

Comment: @Preciel - You are reading the HttpFoundation component documentation which basically talks about how to do things in your own framework.  The Symfony framework already takes care of these details for you.  $session = $request->getSession() and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first a big thanks to [Gopal Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2689199/gopal-joshi) who helped me figure out a lot of things... :)

For those who come later, read his answer, it's helpful in a lot of ways...
I would also suggest reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464624/redirect-with-event-listener-for-all-no-route-found-404-not-found-notfoundhtt), it goes in pair with the current question.

Meanwhile, I came out with this:

**1: Register the service**

**<kbd>AppBundle\Resources\config\services.yml</kbd>**

```
app.session_handler:
    class: SalonBundle\Services\SessionHandler
    arguments:
        - "@doctrine"
        - "@router"
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: setSession }
```

First, I will point that I use the argument `@router`, but unless you need to redirect the response to another url, it's not needed.

**2: Create the service**

**<kbd>AppBundle\EventListener\SessionHandler.php</kbd>**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class SessionHandler {

    private $doctrine;
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Registry $doctrine, Router $router) {
        //Make sure to type $doctrine and $router in the constructor.
        //Else some methods can't be found directly, and Symfony have to do the job for you
        //I guess it would make a big project a bit slower without the types
        $this->doctrine=$doctrine;
        $this->router=$router;
    }

    public function setSession(GetResponseEvent $responseEvent) {
        //This function parameter call on GetResponseEvent class
        //for the same reason as above.
        $site=$this->doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:Site')->findOneBy(array('url'=>$responseEvent->getRequest()->getSchemeAndHttpHost()));
        if($site) {
            $session=$responseEvent->getRequest()->getSession();
            $session->clear();
            $session->set('site', $site);
        } else {
            if($responseEvent->getRequest()->get('_route') != 'some_route') {
                //This next line is the only reason as to why we pass "@router" as argument
                $responseEvent->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('some_route')));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To sum things up, it's very close to [Gopal Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2689199/gopal-joshi) answer...
In fact, it's the same, just with some code cleanup...
Both his answer and mine are working...
The only difference is that mine won't show warning like:
`Method 'methodName()' not found` or `import 'import\path\and\name' is never used`

[Gopal Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2689199/gopal-joshi), if you happen to read my answer, I'm asking you, which one should I validate?
Being honest here, most of the credits is yours, so I will validate the answer you want... ;)

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem has been solved :) Both of the answers are mostly same, Additionally you did cleanup the code which would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting Sessions from controller is:

`$session = $this->get("session");`

Setter:   `$session->set('id','<value>');`

Getter:   `$session->get('id');`

**Full Code**

```
public function sessionAction(Request $request) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $site = $em->getRepository('SiteBundle:Site')->findOneBy(array('url'=>$request->getSchemeAndHttpHost()));
    if($site) {
        $session = $this->get("session");
        $session->set('id',$site->getId());
        $session->set('url',$site->getUrl());
        $session->set('name',$site->getName());
    } else {
        [...]
    }
}
```

**Update-1**:

Create service to set session variables

**AppBundle\EventListener\SessionHandler.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class SessionHandler {

    private $doctrine;
    private $container;
    private $router;

    public function __construct($doctrine, $router, $container) {
        $this->doctrine  = $doctrine;
        $this->router    = $router;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function setSession() {
        $route = $this->container->get('request')->get('_route');
        $site = $this->doctrine->getRepository('SiteBundle:Site')->findOneBy(array('url' => $route->getUri()));
        if($site) {
            $session = $this->container->get("session");
            $session->set('id',$site->getId());
            $session->set('url',$site->getUrl());
            $session->set('name',$site->getName());
        } else {
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

**AppBundle\Resources\config\services.yml**

> Option-1

Call `setSession()` function on each page load event.

```
session_handler:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\SessionHandler
        arguments: [@doctrine, @router, @service_container]
        tags:
            - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: setSession}
```

> Option-2

Call `setSession()` function manually where you need to set session.

```
session_handler:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\SessionHandler
        arguments: [@doctrine, @router, @service_container]
        tags:
            - {name: kernel.event_listener }
```

Call `setSession()` function from controller

```
$sessionService = $this->get('session_handler');
$sessionService->setSession();
```

Comment: He is asking 'where' and not 'how'. He knows how to work with the session bag.

Comment: I think you haven't read comments yet. Read Abhinav Kumar's comment, session is auto initiated in Symfony. Than, no need to explanation for 'where'. He has already use the authenticated function here.

Comment: @Preciel than you can create service and call it on each kernel request. Let me update my answer

Comment: I think Vangoso understood it better than anyone so far. I'm indeed asking where (and how) to call `sessionAction()` when I load the site, not how the session bag works... Symfony doc tells that much. Read my last comment after Jared comment above (sorry @Gopal Joshi , had to delete to edit). And sure, take your time to edit, if it can help me get a better understanding, I'm taking everything in... :)

Comment: I don't think that's the proper way to work with sessions. Not every page will need sessions and you'll be always getting inside of the service.

Comment: @Vangoso If Preciel wants to session in specific pages than he can use option-2.

Comment: Yes. I know that. But he's asking also for the best way to do it and he cares about good practices.

Comment: @GopalJoshi Thnx for support i have a same issue and this code is working in my case.

Comment: @GopalJoshi : Well, all of your advices helped me a lot... With them and another post I found here, I managed to get what I wanted. I will write a proper solution, yours helped me, but isn't the "right" way to do it either (close though). Thanks a lot!