# Symfony generate css

Tags: symfony

I need a little help.
Imagine that in database for every user have stored color of background.
Everytime when user login, first for that user in some folder is generated css file with name of id of user and included in html template.

I need help to understand how to generate css file ?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using for authenticating users? FOSUserBundle?

Comment: Yes, I'm using FOSUserBundle.

Answer (score 0):

I Symfony with FOSUserBundle, you can use `app.user` to get the user in your twig files.

If you open a MySQL console and enter `describe fos_user;` then you will see all the fields you can use in your Twig file. So in your table you could store for each of the FOS users a `color`

Then in Twig you could use something like this:

```
{% if app.user %}
    {% set backColor = app.user.color  %}
{% else %}
    {% set backColor = 'none'  %}
{% endif %}
...
<body style="background-color:{{ backColor }};">
```

You get the idea...
You might want to figure out a way to store the color preference for the FOS user using a Symfony form. And then store preference in database. You can raise a separate question for that if you have difficulties - it should be easy.

Answer (score -1):

Quite simple...

You need to generate a twig file for every user in your desired folder, and place "inline" CSS in it.

```
{% block css %}
    <style>
        .class {
            parameter: {{ entity.value }};
        }
    </style>
{% endblock css %}
```

To generate the file, create a service, which you will call when a page is loaded.
It will have to first check if the file exist, if it does, it will read from it (no query to the DB), if not, it will generate the file, and read need data from DB.

Look at answer from me and Gopal on this page to know how to make a service [How to use session in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711807/how-to-use-session-in-symfony).
You sould be able to use it for your need... ;)
Also look at the [Symfony Filesystem Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html)

`file_put_contents()` should help you write content of the file... ;)

Comment: Thanks. This part is clear. Example, you have one standar css file. But you have some folders where are you storing pictures and other things. Lets call Data, inside data you have folders from 1 to n, where n is id of user. So inside of folder n you have css file which will be included in html. how I can generate this css file based on data from database ?

Comment: Sorry, did read a bit too fast, edited my answer, this should help you a bit more... ;)

Comment: Using sessions in not a good way to store user info. In fact, it's not permanent...

Comment: @AlvinBunk I'm not asking him to use session to store user infos, I told him to look at the link to see about how to create a service...