# Symfony: How To set Cookies and Session variable in an include Twig Controller?

Tags: session, cookies, controller, twig, symfony

This is my first post, then if there is/are any problem let me know :)

I'm building a website using Symfony, but I currently got a problem:
I can't set (or certainly I missed something) cookie and session variable in an include Twig controller `{{ render(controller("AcmeCoreBundle:Auth:index")) }}` (this controller have to allow 'connection' from each website page)

I have created the form using the entity `WhoIsIt` and the form type `WhoIsIt`

```
<?php

namespace Acme\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Acme\CoreBundle\Form\WhoIsItType;
use Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\WhoIsIt;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $who = new WhoIsIt;
        $session = $this->get('session');
        $response = new Response();
        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(WhoIsItType::class, $who);

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
          $form->handleRequest($request);
          if ($form->isValid()) {
              $whoisit = $form->getData();
              //I set Cookie and Session variables

              $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('personality', $whoisit->getPersonality(), time() + 3600 * 24 * 3));
              $session->set('personality', $whoisit->getPersonality());
              $response->setContent($this->render('AcmeCoreBundle:Form:Auth.html.twig', array(
                        'form' => $form->createView())));
              return $response;
          }
    }

    $cookies = $request->cookies;
    $who->setPersonality($this->setDefault('personality', 'personality.supporter', $cookies, $session));
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(WhoIsItType::class, $who);
    $response->setContent($this->render('AcmeCoreBundle:Form:Auth.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView())));
    return $response;
}

private function setDefault($element, $default, $cookies, $session)
{
//This fonction help me to define the default value of the form
    if ($session->has($element))
    {
        return $session->get($element);
    }
    elseif ($cookies->has($element))
    {
        return $cookies->get($element);
    }
    return $default;
}
}
```

When I look for the response in Symfony Profiler I just get a POST PARAMETER:

```
who_is_it   [ personality => personality.supporter, validate => ], _token => 9ACFB8AO53e7M5QMoqyptVhNqOj933SoMYRfKZsNRJ4 ]
```

And don't get Cookie nor Session variable named `personality`

I would like to know if it's possible to set cookie/session in a SubRequest?
And If that is possible, what should I change in my code?

I hope you understand my problem :) If you don't, or need more precision please let me know with a comment.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution to my problem.

For my firs problem, I needed to give the original request as parameter:

```
{{ render(controller("AcmeCoreBundle:Auth:index", {'cookies': app.request.cookies})) }}
```

And do some other hack (js redirection etc...)

But, now I use another controller to catch the 'POST', for that, when I create the form I need to specify an option:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(WhoIsItType::class, $who, array(
                        'action' => $this->generateUrl('acme_core_auth'))
                        );
```

Then I create the correct Action:

```
public function authAction (Request $request)
    {
        $who = new WhoIsIt;
        $session = $this->get('session');
        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(WhoIsItType::class, $who);
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $whoisit = $form->getData();                    
                $response = new RedirectResponse($request->headers->get('referer')); //Here I create a redirection to the current webpage
                $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('personality', $whoisit->getPersonality(), time() + 3600 * 48)); I set a new cookie in the response header
                $session->set('personality', $whoisit->getPersonality()); // I update session var
                return $response;         

            }
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('acme_core_homepage'); //If not in post/valid I redirect to the homepage
    }
```

Finally the code is:

<kbd>Acme\CoreBundle\Controller\AuthController.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace Acme\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Acme\CoreBundle\Form\WhoIsItType;
use Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\WhoIsIt;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($cookies)
    {

        $who = new WhoIsIt;
        $session = $this->get('session');
        $who->setPersonality($this->setDefault('personality', 'eventType.All', $cookies, $session));
        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(WhoIsItType::class, $who, array(
                            'action' => $this->generateUrl('acme_core_auth'))
                            );
        return $this->render('AcmeCoreBundle:Form:Auth.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()));
    }

    public function authAction (Request $request)
    {
        $who = new WhoIsIt;
        $session = $this->get('session');
        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(WhoIsItType::class, $who);
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $whoisit = $form->getData();
                $response = new RedirectResponse($request->headers->get('referer'));
                $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('personality', $whoisit->getPersonality(), time() + 3600 * 48));
                $session->set('personality', $whoisit->getPersonality());
                return $response;         
            }
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('acme_core_homepage');
    }

    //This set default according to the order session>cookies>default
    private function setDefault($element, $default, $cookies, $session)
    {
        if ($session->has($element))
        {
            return $session->get($element);
        }
        if ($cookies->has($element))
        {
            $default = $cookies->get($element);
        }
        $session->set($element, $default);
        return $default;
    }
}
```

I hope this could help somebody else :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I created my session when I get to my site:
I needed to check the site url to find the right entity. Hope it will help you.

**1: Register the service**

**<kbd>AppBundle\Resources\config\services.yml</kbd>**

```
app.session_handler:
    class: SalonBundle\Services\SessionHandler
    arguments:
        - "@doctrine"
        - "@router"
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: setSession }
```

First, I will point that I use the argument `@router`, but unless you need to redirect the response to another url, it's not needed.

**2: Create the service**

**<kbd>AppBundle\EventListener\SessionHandler.php</kbd>**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;

class SessionHandler {

    private $doctrine;
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Registry $doctrine, Router $router) {
        //Make sure to type $doctrine and $router in the constructor.
        //Else some methods can't be found directly, and Symfony have to do the job for you
        //I guess it would make a big project a bit slower without the types
        $this->doctrine=$doctrine;
        $this->router=$router;
    }

    public function setSession(GetResponseEvent $responseEvent) {
        //This function parameter call on GetResponseEvent class
        //for the same reason as above.
        $accessor=PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
        //accessor will be used to get a parameter from an entity stored in session.
        $session=$responseEvent->getRequest()->getSession();
        //Fetching the existing session
        $site=$session->get('site');
        //Fetching object in session, return null if doesn't exists
        $url=$responseEvent->getRequest()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
        //Fetching my site current base URL
        if(!$site) {
            //If site isn't in session
            $site=$this->doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:Site')->findOneBy(array('url'=>$url));
            //Fetch object based on site URL
            if($site) {
                //If found, send it to session to make sure we don't keep searching for it on each page loading
                $session->clear();
                $session->set('site', $site);
            } else {
                //Else send to dashboard and go create it
                if($responseEvent->getRequest()->get('_route') != 'dashboard_site') {
                    $responseEvent->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('dashboard_site')));
                }
            }
        } else {
            //If site is in session
            if($accessor->getValue($site, 'url') != $url) {
                //Use of accessor to fetch url param from site object and check if object url is same as website url
                $site=$this->doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:Site')->findOneBy(array('url'=>$url));
                if($site) {
                    $session->clear();
                    $session->set('site', $site);
                } else {
                    if($responseEvent->getRequest()->get('_route') != 'dashboard_site') {
                        $responseEvent->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('dashboard_homepage')));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would also suggest reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464624/redirect-with-event-listener-for-all-no-route-found-404-not-found-notfoundhtt), it goes in pair with the current question.

Comment: Hello, thank you very Much for your interest and your very detailled answer. I'm not really familiar with services at the moment. Then I continued to dig and found a solution to my problem that is not using service. Will post my solution, hope this will help.